# UV Unwrap End of a Pipe

Tags: uv

I have a pipe-like mesh that I need to unwrap so that it'll accept a brick texture. The sides of the pipe are easy. My problem is trying to figure out a way to unwrap the ends so that I can have a single row of brick texture continue around radially.

Okay, not an easy thing to say with words. How about a picture...

[image: Radially unwrap the end of the pipe.]

I used the grease pencil to give an idea of how the desired unwrap will look.

Thanks for any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Select the end faces, hit <kbd>U</kbd> button to unwrap and select **Reset** from the menu.
2. Hit <kbd>U</kbd> button again and chose **Follow Active Quads**.
3. Scale and move the unwrapped faces in the UV/Image editor to desired location.

Comment: Wow! Perfect! I always wondered what the Follow Active Quads mode did.